# Shell - read html into variable and filter sequence

Tags: html, shell, curl

I need to read a webpage with tables into a variable and filter the number of one cell out.

the html is like:

```
<tr><th>Totals:</th><td> 99999.9</td>
```

I need to get that 99999.9 number.

I tried:

```
value=$(curl -s -m 10 http://$host |  egrep -o "Totals:</th><td> [0-9]\{5\}" | cut -d'> ' -f 2)
```

an other valid option is to check if the page is generated at least. I mean reading the html into an value and check if the value is full of html (maybe length).

any glue what is wrong about the curl command combined with the cut command?

thank you?

Comment: No one has a glue? Is it that difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a proper `html` parser for that. If you really want to do it with `bash` (which is ***error prone*** and can cause you lot of headache if the html getting more complex) you can do that in the following way:

```
# html="$(curl -s -m 10 http://$host)"
html="<tr><th>Totals:</th><td> 99999.9</td>"

# remove all whitespaces
# it is not guaranteed that your cell value will be on the same line with Totals:
html_cl="$(echo $html | tr -d ' \t\n\r\f')"

# strip .*Totals:</th><td> before the desired cell value
# strip </td>.* after the value
value="${html_cl##*Totals:</th><td>}"
value="${value%%</td>*}"
echo $value
```

Gives you the result:

```
99999.9
```

***NOTE***: If you have multiple `Totals` with the same tags then it will extract only the last one from your string.

Comment: the thing is, I execute the script on a synology diskstation. I wil giveit a try. thank you!

Comment: Let me know your outcome.

Comment: this works great, accepted! can You let me know how to convert the result in float?

Comment: Bash only supports integer arithmetic operations. You must use an external tool that can handle it, for example `bc`. For example: `v=99999.9; bc <<< $v+$v`

Comment: just need to compare the value to another integer

Comment: if (( $(echo "$num1 > $num2" | bc -l) )); then echo "NUM1 ($num1) is greater"; else echo "NUM1 ($num1) is less or equal than NUM2 ($num2)"; fi

Comment: bc: command not found the diskstation doesnt know the command. any alternative?

Comment: just took the integer value : with value=${value%%.*} and then received the integer

Comment: Okay, i thought you wanted to compare this float value with an integer one. The way how you extracted the integer part of that number is perfect. Now you can compare integers in bash without external tools.